# How do I extend the program to then declare the smallest number?

Tags: java, user-defined-functions

Can I extend the program’s functionality to additionally tell the user the smallest number, by creating a separate method, smaller, in a similar fashion to the larger method?

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println("Please enter two numbers");

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    int first = scan.nextInt();
    int second = scan.nextInt();

    System.out.println("The largest "+larger(first, second));

}// end of main

public static double larger(double x, double y)
{
    if (x >= y)
        return x;

    return y;
} //end of larger
```

Comment: Yes, you surely can.

Comment: You need to edit either your question or your title.  Are you wanting to know IF you can do it (absolutely) or "how" to do it?  If the question is "how" you ought to show what you've tried that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This is trivial, e.g. (keeping the same code conventions)

```
  public static double smaller(double x, double y)
  {
    if (x >= y)
        return y;

        return x;
  } //end of larger
```

The above is not optimal, but it aligns with the existing code.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use *`Math.min(double a, double b)`*, or ternary operator: *`a < b ? a : b`*. 
P.S. One number is not greater than another if they are equal.